# Spring SOAP WebService-Masking elements of XML Request payload in Log

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, jaxb

As part of security requirement, I need to mask sensitive field values like creditcard number etc while logging the XML SOAP request payload using log4j.
Currently I am using the following code to log the XML request payload:

```
public void printDebugXMLPayload(MyWSRequest request) throws JAXBException
{
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyWSRequest .class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(request,  new StreamResult(sw));
    logger.debug(sw.toString());
  
}
```

The above code logs the complete XML request payload but I need to mask the sensitive fields.
Could you please guide. Many Thanks!
Note: I couldn't find any config at @XmlElement level to mask the fields

Answer (score 0):

one way is to create a custom annotation and use reflection class to see if the field needs to be masked.
here's a quick sample.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Mask {
}
```

```
public class MyWSRequest {
    @Mask
    private String item1;
}
```

```
public void printDebugXMLPayload(MyWSRequest request) throws JAXBException {
    for (Field f : request.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (f.isAnnotationPresent(Mask.class)) {
            logger.debug("***");
        } else {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            logger.debug(f.get(request));
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks, kindly let us know if there is a way in jaxb using xmlelement to mask the fields